# Django migration allow_migrate() missing 1 required positional argument 'model'

Tags: django, migration

I'm trying to update my django application from version 1.8.18 to 1.11.1 and facing following problem **TypeError: allow_migrate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'**

I searched a web and didn't find solution for my problem. Here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/projects/TcellIDM/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/projects/TcellIDM/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/srv/projects/TcellIDM/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/srv/projects/TcellIDM/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/srv/projects/TcellIDM/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/srv/projects/TcellIDM/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 30, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/srv/projects/TcellIDM/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1282, in check
    errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
  File "/srv/projects/TcellIDM/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1357, in _check_fields
    errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
  File "/srv/projects/TcellIDM/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 909, in check
    errors = super(AutoField, self).check(**kwargs)
  File "/srv/projects/TcellIDM/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 219, in check
    errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/srv/projects/TcellIDM/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 321, in _check_backend_specific_checks
    if router.allow_migrate(db, app_label, model_name=self.model._meta.model_name):
  File "/srv/projects/TcellIDM/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 300, in allow_migrate
    allow = method(db, app_label, **hints)
TypeError: allow_migrate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'
```

Please help me to detect problem location or suggest me where should I go to solve the problem.

Comment: The traceback suggests you have a problem with your database router. The [`allow_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate) method appears to have the wrong signature.

Comment: @Alasdair thank you. I'll try to search that way.

Answer (score 1):

The `DATABASE_ROUTERS` setting appears not to be able to accept a list of classes, only a list of dotted paths to classes.

Instead of this:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [MyRouterClass]
```

Do this:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp.routers.MyRouterClass']
```

where this particular router class lives in `myapp/routers.py`. If like me you were defining your router within your settings file, I suspect you'll need to move it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label=None, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
    database.
    """
    if app_label == 'auth':
        return db == 'xxxx'
    return None
```

Maybe you can add the model_name=None.
I got a similar Error with the app_lable.